# I have to make a ruby game of guessing a random number that incorporates functions but keep getting errors

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

Here is the code:
First the check function

```
  def check ( int, r_int)
    if int < r_int
    puts "Guess Higher"
    tries = tries + 1

    elsif int > r_int
    puts "Guess Lower"
    trie = tries + 1
    
    elsif int == r_int
    win = true
    puts "You are correct"
    puts "You had attempted this "+ tries.to_s + " times to win"
    
    gets.chomp

    end


end
```

Then this is the main function:

```
def main

tries = 0
win = false

puts "Lets play a game!"
puts "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100"
puts "Have a guess"
rnd_int = rand(100)

while not win

    guess = gets.chomp.to_i
    value = check (guess, rnd_int)
    puts value.to_s
    
    


end

end

main
```

Here is the error:
number_game.rb:42: **syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
value = check (guess, rnd_int)**
Not sure what to do here

Comment: The error is on line 42 of `number_game.rb` I'm not sure which line of your code that relates to... but note that you should NOT put a space between a method and it's arguments if there are multiple arguments.  replace `check (guess, rnd_int)` with `check(guess, rnd_int)` and also remove the space following `def check`.  The reason for this is if you have a space, it will treat the arguments as a single argument `(guess, rnd_int)` instead of two arguments `guess` and `rnd_int`

Comment: number_game.rb is the name of the file. Thank you will try now

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Tip: For integer numerical values if you've tested `a > b` and `a < b` then the only remaining possibility is `a == b`, so you can just `else` that. No reason to be specific about it.

Comment: Tip: To avoid typos like `trie = tries + 1`, use `tries += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring on this line:

```
value = check (guess, rnd_int)
```

When calling a method you should not have a space between the method name and the argument list.  In this case the proper way to call the method would be:

```
value = check(guess, rnd_int)
```

The error can be a little confusing.  It is telling you that the Ruby interpreter is confused by the  `)`.  This tells you that the error is likely before this point in your code.

Check out some documentation on methods for more information: https://www.w3resource.com/ruby/ruby-methods.php